# How to create jar file from project located in separate folders?

Tags: java

I write a project that locate in 3 separate folder  :

1. Operator interface(d:\operatorAPI)
2. Main part of my program(d:\project.main.FileProcess)
3. four operator classes `Plus`, `Minus`, `Multiply`, `Divide` (d:\operators).

This folders has dependencies for example  :class `Plus`,`Minus`, `Divide`, `Multiply` implement `Operator` interface, in main program I load classes in operators dynamically and so on.

Now I want to create a **Jar** file from `operatorAPI` and my main program (the out put should be two jar files:`operatorAPI` & `project.main.FileProcess` and operators folder)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: No I should create jar file form command line

Answer (score 0):

You can do this Using Command prompt.

Suppose your file location is D:/Java/Someproject

Go to command prompt and type the location of project.

```
`cd D/Java/Someproject`
```

Hit Enter

And execute the below code :

```
`jar cfv Someproject.jar`
```

C will create jar , F will transfer file to same project folder, and V will print the result in console.

Comment: I should create jar file from my interface and main program but all these three folder have dependencies .when I use your way I get classaNotDefFoundException